# Yii2 Gridview display all columns

Tags: yii2

How can I display all columns in gridview without define the columns that I want to displau in view ?

In Yii2 doc,

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [ //define columns here
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at:datetime',
        // ...
    ],
]) ?>
```

Can we just

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => '*',
]) ?>
```

Comment: its not just the data column that it has to render but it can be a `SerialColumn` or `ActionColumn` e.t.c too so just * wont help also the method that initializes these columns [`initColumns()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#initColumns()-detail) is declared as `protected` so you cant override it too to add your own implementation for it. so just either dont specify columns option and let the `guessColumn()` do the work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a wildcard, but you can use `attributes()` method on your model (if you have an instance) or `array_keys(Model::getTableSchema()->columns);`

Comment: ‘Columns’ => [],    Is all you need (or simple remove the columns row altogether.  So long a NOTHING is passed for the columns parameter, then all columns will be displayed